# Create automatic low & high res pdf, png with inDesign for multiple user

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, indesign-scripting, data-merge

I am working on a platform, which should create from an inDesign file a low and high-res pdf, a png and maybe a new indesign file with the new data.

These steps are in my mind.

1. User logins or create a new login with his personal data, for
   example: firstname, lastname, address, telephone and web.
2. There is an indesign file for example a business card, with
   placeholders for firstname etc.
3. The script / plugin / addon should open the file with the xml,csv
   and create these files and save it automatically in a dir.
4. I can work with these files

When you guys know a software, plugin, ... which can handle it, it would be awesome when you could help me.